# How can I resolve Scala package name conflicts?

Tags: scala, package

```
package net.kolotyluk

package object leaderboard {
  def randomLong: Long = {
    val random = scala.util.Random
    random.setSeed(System.nanoTime)
    random.nextLong
  }
}
```

Fails to compile with

```
[error] D:\Users\erick\repos\leaderboard\src\main\scala\net\kolotyluk\leaderboard\package.scala:7:24: object util is not a member of package net.kolotyluk.scala
[error]     val random = scala.util.Random
[error]                        ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

I suspect the problem is I have package `net.kolotyluk.scala.extras` defined elsewhere. Why is it that Scala cannot find `scala.util.Random`? This seems like a defect in either the Scala compiler, or the Scala language itself.

Is there a way to import/specify an absolute package name instead of the relative package name which seems to be used here?

Using `import __root__.scala.util.Random` does not seem to work either as mentioned in https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/packages-and-imports.html because

```
[error] D:\Users\erick\repos\leaderboard\src\main\scala\net\kolotyluk\leaderboard\package.scala:3:8: not found: object __root__
[error] import __root__.scala.util.Random
[error]        ^
```

Answer (score 5):

Doh! the documentation at https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/packages-and-imports.html is wrong. It should be `_root_` not `__root__`